# Python 3: graph full date with pyplot

Tags: python, date, matplotlib, time

Okay, so I'm trying to plot the full date on the xaxis of a pyplot graph. The date is in the standard format, 2015-11-20 00:01:00
I've converted it into a number with he following code...

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# xList is obtained from a csv file, it's a list of strings
xList = ['2015-11-20 00:01:00' for u in range(100)]
x = [mdates.date2num(datetime.datetime.strptime(op,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')) for op in xList]
# yes that line is horrible, but it was okay for the playground
# I convert the string into the date format, and then convert it into a number
y = [u for u in range(len(x))
plt.plot_date(x,y)
plt.show()
```

The result is a diagonal line (really think for some reason when plot_date is used) with just the time part of the date on the x axis. This is a problem because my data spans mutable days, and I'd like to be able to tell which day events occurred.

I've also tried passing just the converted date format (without the mdates.date2num applied) and I get the same result.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of plot_date, just use the plot function. However, add in

```
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
plt.plot(x,range(len(x))
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
```

when you call the plot function.

Comment: Awesome, that worked, thanks! I tried that before without the first line though.